# Sent binary data to stdout - garbled console - does this affect my system?

Tags: linux, console, binary-data

Sometimes it happens that binary data is sent accidentally to stdout on linux console or ssh session, e.g.:

> head binary-file

As as result you sometimes get a really garbled console which can be reset. This is ok. But my question is: Is there a chance that the system gets somehow affected by this?

For example:

- unwanted commands being executed
- files overwritten or damaged